# listfragment inside a fragment how to get list

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment, android-nested-fragment

I've got a listfragment inside a fragment. I want to get the list inside the parent fragment, in the onActivityCreated but i can't figure out how to do so.
I want to do that because the list is a custom listview with 2 textview and a checkbox and i need to see which items are checked.

My parent fragment :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getChildFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.list_topgain_frame, new ListFragmentTopGain())
    .commit();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.parier3, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    btnGainValider = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnGainValider);
    btnGainValider.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

The frame layout that i replace with the ListFragment :

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_choixamis_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txvChoixAmis"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a little trick cause i still can't find how to get the list in the parent fragment..

Anyway, if someone else had this issue, I bypassed by using a listener in my customAdapter. then i pass the information : customAdapter -> ListFragment -> ParentFragment.